# Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable. Then, $ P(X<0\mid |[X]| = 1)$ is equal to?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

> Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable. Then, $ P(X<0\mid |[X]| = 1)$ is equal to-
>
> 1. $\frac{\Phi(1)-\frac{1}{2}}{\Phi(2)-\frac{1}{2}}$
> 2. $\frac{\Phi(1)+\frac{1}{2}}{\Phi(2)+\frac{1}{2}}$
> 3. $\frac{\Phi(1)-\frac{1}{2}}{\Phi(2)+\frac{1}{2}}$
> 4. $\frac{\Phi(1)-1}{\Phi(2)+1}$

My work:

First I didn't understood what is mean by $|[X]|=1$. Is it absolute value of floor of $X$? Then $$P(X<0\mid |[X]| = 1)=\frac{P(X<0, |[X]| = 1)}{P( |[X]| = 1)}.$$ Now I am stuck. Don't know how to proceed further. How can I do this? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to know what $[X]$ is to make sense of this. By the way, the standard normal CDF is usually denoted by $\Phi$ (\Phi in LaTeX).

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't understood @Ian. The question is as I posted. It is greatest integer function I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $|[X]|$ means absolute value of floor of $X$, that is $1$ if and only if $X \in [-1,0) \cup [1,2)$.  So $$P(X<0||[X]|=1) = \dfrac{P(X \in [-1,0])}{P(X \in [-1,0)) + P(X \in [1,2))}$$
Also useful will be symmetry, so $P(X \in [-1,0)) = P(X \in [0,1))$.

Comment: How did you deduce the interval i.e. $X \in [-1,0) \cup [1,2)$?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan $|[X]|=1$ implies $[X]$ is either $1$ or $-1$. For $[X]=1$, you need $X$ to be in the interval $[1,2)$; for $[X]=-1$, you need $X$ to be in the interval $[-1,0)$.

Comment: @angryavian Oh got it